# How to fix " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value " outlet button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, fatal-error, iboutlet

When I try to do Play.hidden = true , I get the error message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  My button outlets are connected.

[image: Connected Outlets]

Here's my code(inside of viewController class) :

```
 @IBOutlet weak var Play: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Stop: UIButton!
```

Here's my method:

```
 @IBAction func recordButton(sender: AnyObject) {
   Play.hidden = true

}
```

Here's another screenshot:

[image: Screenshot xcode]
Any suggestions would help. Thank you!

Comment: When you say `outletName.disabled = true`, are you referring to `Play.hidden = true` or to any `outletName.enabled = true`?

Comment: It looks like your outlets are connected, so the other cause I can think of is that the controller that has this code is not the instance you made in the storyboard. How did this controller get on screen?

Comment: did you try self.Play.hidden = true ?

Comment: @tyt_g207 yes , I tried that.

Comment: @keithbhunter my mistake. I will fix that right away. Yes, it was suppose to be Play.hidden = true.

Comment: @rdelmar I dragged a View Controller into the space in storyboard. I then connected it with viewController swift class.

Comment: Did you set the `UIViewController`'s class in the interface builder to be `ViewController`, instead of the default `UIViewController`?

Comment: @keithbhunter under "Custom Class" , I set the class to "viewController". If that's what you mean. Then yes.

Comment: Does `(sender as UIButton).hidden = true` work?

Comment: @HAS Yes, sender hides the recordButton. But I'd like the play button to be hidden when I click the recordButton .

Comment: @htjohn My bad! Of course ... Have you tried disconnecting the play button outlet and connecting it again?

Comment: @HAS YES! That worked ! Wow..Thank you! I was so frustrated .

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys for all your suggestions . I just disconnected the play button outlet and connected it again(Credit to @HAS).[I also renamed the Outlet from "Play" to "playButton" because I have a variable `var play = AVAudioPlayer() .`

I'm not sure what the reason was but it is now fixed.

Comment: In addition to these, I had to restart Xcode to make it work!